# On domains of convergence of series of several complex variables.

Tags: complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

I know that for every series of several complex variables $$\sum_{k_1+...+k_n=0}^\infty a_{k_1,...,k_n}z_1^{k_1}\cdots z_n^{k_n}$$ its domain of convergence $G$ is logarithmically convex (that is, $\log G=\{(\log z_1,...,\log z_n):z_i\in G\}$ is a convex set in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$) Reinhardt domain.
But for a series
$$\sum_{\mu,\nu=0}^\infty a_{\mu\nu}z_1^\mu z_2^\nu$$
we can describe it's domain of convergence as
$$
\begin {cases}
|z_1|=\varphi(|z_1|),&& 0\leq|z_1|\leq R\\
|z_2|=R,&&0\leq|z_2|<\varphi(R)
\end{cases},$$
where $\varphi$ is continuous and non-decreasing.
I know that this set has to be logarithmically convex Reinhardt domain, so what can be said about $\varphi$ to guarantee that is the case? Is it enough to demand that $$\log\circ\varphi$$ is a convex function?

Comment: Let $f$ a power series $U_f= \{ z, f(tz)$ converges for $|t| < 1\}$ and $L(U_f)=\{(\ln|z_1|,\ldots,\ln |z_n|),z \in U_f\}$. If $U_f$ contains a small polydisk then it is closed and radial and $L(U_f)$ is convex containing $(-\infty,a]^n$ for some $a$. Conversely if $U,L(U)$ are like this then there is some power series with $U_f = U$ (since $U$ is the limit of a sequence of convex polytopes, for each hyperplane pick a power series $f_j$ whose convergence boundary is that hyperplane then look at $\sum_j c_jf_j$).