# Domain of convergence in several complex variables

Tags: complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

I am trying to understand how to calculate the ***domain of convergence*** for the series [From: *Tasty Bits of Several Complex Variables*] :

$$ \sum_{j,k} c_{j,k}\; z_1^j z_2^k $$

But I don't really understand how to handle the $c_{j,k}$ term. I saw a past [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3224878/on-domains-of-convergence-of-series-of-several-complex-variables)(and a few more but they did not help me either), but I don't understand the result it presents. (Of course the other examples like $\sum_{k}z_1 z_2^k$, $\sum_{j,k} z_1^j z_2^k$, are very clear.)

Can we actually derive some general result for any $c_{j,k}$? Or do we need some information about it?

Answer (score 3):

The domain of convergence is a logarithmically convex complete Reinhardt domain, and nothing more can be said without knowing what the coefficients are. Every such domain is the domain of convergence for some power series.